# How to dynamically retrieve a CDI dependency?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, wildfly-8, inject

I'm trying to dynamically retrieve a dependency for my Java code.

I know the class name, but I want to take the instance managed by the container, with proper indirect dependencies resolved.

For example:

```
class Foo {

    public static void foo() {
        Bar bar = (Bar) getDependency("com.example.Bar");
        bar.bar();
    }

}

class Bar {

     @Inject
     private Spam spam;

     public void bar() {
         spam.spam();
     }

}
```

I can't construct a `Bar` instance myself because I wouldn't be able to inject the correct `Spam`. So I want as if `Foo` had injected a `Bar` into it. I can't add a field like `@Inject Bar bar` because the exact name of the dependency varies in runtime.

Any way to do this?

I'm using WildFly 8.2.0.

Comment: *"because the exact name of the dependency varies in runtime."* What does it mean? The type may vary? If so then classes which can be injected can implement the same interface, then you can create `@Qualifier` with value unique for every class and `@Inject` desired implementation as an interface. What can come in handy is: [`Instance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) interface or [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation.

Comment: That's right. The type varies. I will use a common interface to all of them. The problem is that I need a runtime information to know which "qualifier" to use. I can't say which dependency to use statically.

Comment: Let's say you have class `A` and `B` and `@MyImpl` qualifier which have `String` value. You annotate class `A` with `@MyImpl(value = "A")` and the same goes for B. When you use `Instance` interface you can use `select` method to find your implementation. If you want class `A` to be injected you say: "Give me object of class with `@MyImpl` qualifier and "A" value". Then the class `A` will be injected. "A" value may be a variable that vary at runtime. https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject BeanManager beanManager;

    public void foo() {
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Bar.class);
        Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beans);
        CreationalContext<?> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean);
        Bar bar = (Bar) beanManager.getReference(bean, Bar.class, creationalContext);   
    }
}
```

or maybe even simpler:

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject Instance<Object> instance;

    public void foo() {
        Bar bar = instance.select(Bar.class).get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the source code](https://gist.github.com/vaclavsvejcar/f6fde0ef44dd3e3eb50d) of the simple `ManualContext` class I've created for one of my projects. It was primarily designed for accessing CDI-managed beans from POJO objects, but maybe it could be helpful for you.

Example of use:

```
final ManualContext mCtx = new ManualContext();
...
final MyBean myBean = mCtx.lookupCDI(MyBean.class);  // obtains the CDI-managed instance
```